# Playing with gcc's intermediate GIMPLE format

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-construction, backend, gimple

According to [this article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_language) gcc uses several intermediate formats before generating code. I read that the GIMPLE format uses three address code, which seems to be the easiest intermediate language to use. But I need some more detail, as I need to build a tool that can take the intermediate code and insert some code to it before generating the final code.

For this I first need to know how can I even generate the GIMPLE format code and save it in a file. So I'm looking for some documents and examples. Also, if anyone has worked with such things, can I know the complexity of this task, which is to insert some code into the intermediate code?

Comment: This is one link, http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/GimpleFrontEnd

Comment: A good example is at http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.3.4/gccint/GIMPLE-Example.html

Comment: if you are looking for a way to generate code, you might look at llvm. At least it is much better documented.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1496497/how-can-i-see-parse-tree-intermediate-code-optimization-code-and-assembly-code

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You might find it easier to write a [plugin](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Plugins.html) for GCC, which would allow you to hook the GIMPLE generation and alter it inside GCC, which should drop the downtime of saving, editing then trying to compile from GIMPLE form. [MELT](http://starynkevitch.net/basile/gcc-melt/GCC-MELT-HiPEAC2012.pdf) is one such plugin (though it offers *way* more than just altering the lower level representations). There is also a nice PDF [here](http://www.fsl.cs.sunysb.edu/ssw/files/Download/gccplugins.pdf) on GIMPLE altering plugins.

Else, you can look [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/GIMPLE.html) for information on how GCC's GIMPLE works. 
In terms of dumping GIMPLE out:

> You can request to dump a C-like representation of the GIMPLE form with the flag -fdump-tree-gimple.

Comment: I'm the main developer of MELT, and I have added a few days ago new tutorial slides on http://gcc-melt.org/GCC-MELT-HiPEAC2012.pdf (there are also other stuff of http://gcc-melt.org/ ...)

Comment: gcc-melt.org is dead, new link is http://starynkevitch.net/basile/gcc-melt/GCC-MELT-HiPEAC2012.pdf

Comment: @Abex pitty the site went down, I have updated with your link, though next time just (propose an) edit to my answer :)

Answer (score 14):

You can easily generate GIMPLE representation of any file using the flag `-fdump-tree-gimple`.

If you want to write a plugin, then you might be interested in how passes work on GCC. You can see the output of each pass with flags of the form:

```
-fdump-<ir>-<passname>
```

where `ir` could be:

- `tree` : Intraprocedural passes on GIMPLE
- `ipa` : Interprocedural passes on GIMPLE
- `rtl` : Intraprocedural passes on RTL

Use `<passname> = all` to see all the dumps, e.g. `-fdump-ipa-all`.

Answer (score 1):

I tried the flag `-fdump-tree-gimple`.  It works only for the C/C++ language, and not for other languages such as Java, Ada, Fortran, and Objective-C)

Comment: The question is tagged C. So the other languages are of no relevance.

Answer (score 1):

It is now possible, since GCC 7, to use `__GIMPLE` in a function's declaration specifiers, along with the `-fgimple` command-line flag, to have GCC directly compile GIMPLE. This is explained in more detail [in the documentation for GCCs internals](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/GIMPLE-Tests.html)

[Similar infrastructure is also available for RTL](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/RTL-Tests.html)