# Is there any way to suppress errors about missing header files in GCC?

Tags: c, gcc, syntax-error, gcc-warning

I need to check 2 million C source files for a research project for simple syntax errors like missing (semicolons, parenthesis, ...). Each file is a function without main() and header files.
With the help of GCC, I have used the following command:

```
gcc -c -fsyntax-only -w file.c
```

My script is doing the job, but the only problem is that almost more than 95% of errors are related to missing header files. I tried to add some of these header files to each function, but the number of these header files seems endless.

**Is there any way to suppress errors about missing header files?**

**Does GCC have a special Flag that I can use for my purpose?**

A sample of errors that are related to header files:

```
error: unknown type name ‘ioreq_t’
error: unknown type name ‘SH7750State’
error: unknown type name ‘int64_t’
error: unknown type name ‘AVCodecContext’
error: unknown type name ‘BlockDriverState’
error: unknown type name ‘PXA2xxLCDState’
```

Also, I appreciate any other solution besides using GCC.

Comment: If the header files can't be found, then how can the compiler use any of the stuff defined in those headers? Not sure what you're looking to achieve, here.

Comment: with missing headers it isnt possible in general to check syntax. Suppose there is a `foo{bar}`. Without a declaration of `foo` how would you know if the syntax is correct?

Comment: Of course not. You can't suppress errors. Your question doesn't make sense.

Comment: Who made "2 million C source files" that aren't compilable?

Comment: I recommend to remove the `c++` tag if you are only interested in C sources. Here is a somewhat related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27714891/is-it-possible-to-get-lexer-output-from-gcc-or-clang

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As workaround, you might create one header which includes all the missing `#include` and use `-include` to force that inclusion on top of examined files.
So you don't edit all files:

```
gcc -include "workaround.h" -c -fsyntax-only -w file.c
```