# In the C++ standard does well-formed means that the code compiles?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, standards, well-formed

The C++ standards defines `well-formed programs` as

> C ++ program constructed according to the syntax rules, diagnosable
>   semantic rules, and the one-definition rule

I am wondering if all well-formed program compile or not (if it is not the case, what types of error make the difference between a well-formed program and a compilable problem). For example would a program containing ambiguity errors considered as well-formed?

Comment: An ambiguity is a violation of *diagnosable semantic rules* so no that is not well formed.

Comment: All well-formed programs will compile (assuming a correct compiler).  But not the reverse.  Violations of the "one definition rule" (ODR) are frequently (even mostly) not caught by the compilation system, for example.

Comment: @davidbak Programs can overflow compiler limits...

Comment: @curiousguy - doesn't the C++ standard say where the compiler is allowed to have limits, maybe even lower bounds on those limits?  (I don't know, that's why I'm asking.)

Comment: @davidbak Exactly, compilers can have limits (lines in a file, statements in a function, nesting of template instanciations...). And there are recommended minimum in the std for these limits (as far as I remember). That's a legalese wildcard for the implementation to not do its work. But it isn't honest to have a "conforming" implementation with tiny limits.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A well-formed program can have undefined behaviour.

It's in a note, and thus not technically authoritative, but it seems that it is intention that termination of compilation (or "translation" as the standard calls it) is within the scope of possible UB:

> [intro.defs]
>
> undefined behavior
>
> behavior for which this document imposes no requirements
> [ Note: Undefined behavior may be expected when this document omits any explicit definition of behavior or when a program uses an erroneous construct or erroneous data.
>
> Permissible undefined behavior ranges from ignoring the situation completely with unpredictable results, to behaving during translation or program execution in a documented manner characteristic of the environment (with or without the issuance of a diagnostic message), to **terminating a translation** or execution (with the issuance of a diagnostic message).
>
> Many erroneous program constructs do not engender undefined behavior; they are required to be diagnosed.
>
> Evaluation of a constant expression never exhibits behavior explicitly specified as undefined in [intro] through [cpp] of this document ([expr.const]).
> — end note
> ]

---

There are also practical implementation limits:

> [implemits]
>
> Because computers are finite, C++ implementations are inevitably limited in the size of the programs they can successfully process.
> Every implementation shall document those limitations where known. This documentation may cite fixed limits where they exist, say how to compute variable limits as a function of available resources, or say that fixed limits do not exist or are unknown.

---

Furthermore, compilers can have, and do have bugs. Well-formed simply means the a standard conforming compiler should compile it (within the limitations mentioned above). A buggy compiler does not necessarily conform to the standard.

---

Lastly, the standard document itself is [not perfect](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html). If there is disagreement about what the rules mean, then it is possible for a program to be well-formed under one interpretation, and ill-formed under another interpretation.

If a compiler disagrees with the programmer or another compiler, then it might fail to compile a program that is believed to be well-formed by the other party.

Answer (score 2):

> I am wondering if all well-formed programs compile or not

### Of course not, in practice.

A typical example is when you ask for [optimizations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimizing_compiler) on a *huge* [translation unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming)) containing long C++ functions.

#### (but in theory, yes)

See of course the [n3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) C++11 standard, or the [C++17](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B17) standard.

This happened to me in the (old) [GCC MELT](http://starynkevitch.net/Basile/gcc-melt/) project. I was *generating* C++ code compiled by [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/), basically using transpiler (or [source to source compilation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source-to-source_compiler)) techniques on Lispy DSL of my invention to generate the C++ code of [GCC plugins](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Plugins.html). See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42277406/841108) and [that](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/285048/40065).

In practice, if you generate a *single* C++ function of a hundred thousand statements, the compiler has trouble in optimizing it.

Large generated C++ functions are possible in GUI code generators (e.g. [FLUID](https://www.fltk.org/doc-1.4/fluid.html)), or with some parser generators such as [ANTLR](https://antlr.org/) (when the underlying input grammar is badly designed), interface generators such as [SWIG](http://swig.org/), or by using preprocessors such as [GPP](https://logological.org/gpp) or [GNU m4](https://www.gnu.org/software/m4/) (like [GNU autoconf](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/) does). C++ `template` expansion may also produce arbitrarily large functions (e.g. when you combine several C++ [container](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container) templates and [ask](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html) the GCC compiler to [optimize](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html) at link-time with `g++ -flto -O2`)

I did benchmark, and experimentally observed in the previous decade that compiling a C++ function of *n* statements may take *O(n<sup>2</sup>)* [time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity) (and IIRC *O(n log n)* [space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_complexity)) with `g++ -O3`. Notice that a good optimizing C++ compiler has to do [register allocation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Register_allocation), [loop unrolling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_unrolling), [inline expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inline_expansion), that some [ABI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface)s (including on [Linux/x86-64](https://github.com/hjl-tools/x86-psABI/wiki/X86-psABI)) mandate passing or returning *small* `struct`-s (or instances of small `class`-s) thru registers. All these optimizations require trade-offs and are hitting some [combinatorial explosion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorial_explosion) wall: in practice, compiler optimization is at least an [intractable problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity_theory#Intractability), and probably an [undecidable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undecidable_problem) one. See also the related [Rice's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice%27s_theorem) and read the [*Dragon Book*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compilers:_Principles,_Techniques,_and_Tools).

You could adapt my [manydl.c](https://github.com/bstarynk/misc-basile/blob/master/manydl.c) program (generating more or less random C code compiled as several [plugin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plug-in_(computing))s then [`dlopen`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html)-ing them on Linux) to emit C++. You'll then be able to do some GCC compiler benchmarks, since that `manydl` program is able to generate hundred thousands plugins containing lots of more or less random C functions. See Drepper's paper [*how to write shared libraries*](https://www.akkadia.org/drepper/dsohowto.pdf) and be aware of [libgccjit](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/jit/).

See also the [blog of the late Jacques Pitrat](http://bootstrappingartificialintelligence.fr/WordPress3/) (1934-oct.2019) for an example of a [C program](https://github.com/bstarynk/caia-pitrat) generating the half millions lines of its own C code, whose design is explained in [this paper](http://jacques.pitrat.pagesperso-orange.fr/A%20Step%20toward%20an%20Artificial%20AI%20Scientist.pdf) and [that book](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/book/10.1002/9780470611791).

Read [*Thriving in a crowded and changing world: C++ 2006--2020*](https://dl.acm.org/doi/pdf/10.1145/3386320)

Comment: This was not an answer I expected but you're absolutely right to point it out!  In fact, with some compilers and some source code it can happen without optimization: some compilers have, for certain features, inefficient algorithms (e.g., exponential behavior) that isn't triggered for "normal" or "reasonable" code that someone would actually write but you might have the bad luck to discover with generated code (and sometimes with very few repetitions of a construct ...)  (Nice links, too!)