# How to dump Parse tree and token info from GCC?

Tags: parsing, gcc, token, tokenize

I want to dump token information (list of all tokens for a c file) and parse tree from GCC compiler. I went through the gcc documentation but it was not clear on how to do it. 
How can I get this information from GCC?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I see parse tree, intermediate code, optimization code and assembly code during COMPILATION?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1496497/how-can-i-see-parse-tree-intermediate-code-optimization-code-and-assembly-code)